# Grails: Use run-script to ppopulate a H2 database

Tags: grails, groovy, run-script

I have got some problem to populate my H2 datatase via the run-script command:

Here is my domain class:

```
class Lab {

String name

static constraints = {
}

String toString() {
    return name
}

static mapping = {
    sort "name"
}
```

}

I generated the controller and view using the grails generate-all command.

I wrote a simple groovy script to add new Lab:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def grailsApplication
def dataSource = ctx.getBean("dataSource")
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

Lab a = new Lab(name: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
assert a.save(flush: true)

if (!a.hasErrors()) {
  println "${a.name} saved successfully!"
}
```

Now, when I run it, everything looks to work fine:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA saved successfully!
| Script scripts/createLab.groovy complete!
```

But when I refresh the webpage page `http://localhost:8080/myapp/lab/index`, I cannot see any new Lab created.

I am using the default H2 database setting.

Did I missed something?

Comment: I don't think, that you need the `sql` there.  Are you running both against the same environment and is your H2 persisted (aka: no `mem` database) or are you testing in parallel?  what are the caching settings in grails?

Comment: So the server is started using run-app, then I want to add some data so I ran the script. The parameters are: h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE (default one). I forgot to mention that the plugin Spring security is installed too (could it be the problem?)

Comment: as this all looks fine then (assert save, same env thus db) my suspect would be caching.  you could use the dbconsole to see at the running app, if the data is actually there.  if there are other means to create new labs, do they show up on the index page?  and if your only problem right now is to get debug data in your debug db, you can also do in the bootstrap (just FYI).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works if I put it in the Bootsrap.groovy file, I just don't understand why it is not working in a separated script. I checked at the database also using the dbconsole and can't see the new lab created.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a h2 memory db called devDB (h2:**mem**:devDb;).

I see two options here. If you like to have a physical file to represent your db you can use file instead mem.

```
h2:file:devDb;
```

Or you can put your scripts insite Bootstrap.groovy, and every time you start your application these records will be generated.

This way:

```
Lab.findOrSaveWhere(name:'AAAAAAAAAA')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion ( url = "jdbc:h2:file:d~/.h2" ) but it didn't change. Once the grails app started, if I run the script to add a new Lab, nothing is really added into the database.

Comment: Try to put this script in Bootstrap.groovy Lab.findOrSaveWhere(name:'AAAAAAAAAA'), don't forget to import your domain class

Comment: Thanks, I already succeed to make it work in the bootsrap, nut I wanted to do it in a separarated script so I could keep adding data while the server is running.

Comment: I suggest you install the [console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console) and then you can do it directly by entering code into the browser (you can make a helper method for it on some class, of course). I think your script and your app are not runnning on the same database.